# Can't show variable values in qt debug mode on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, ubuntu, gdb

I've installed qt 5.2 on ubuntu 12.04. but when I run it in the debug mode variables do not appear in locals and expressions window. I tried right-clicking on the variable and clicking on add expression evaluator but nothing happens. I also tried dragging it to locals and expressions window but instead of its value it puts  in value column and the type column is left empty.

Only for global variables qt shows the correct values.

I tried the same version of qt on a 13.10 ubuntu and it works fine. Can anyone tell me what I should do to fix this?

EDIT:

This is the compile output

```
17:10:23: Running steps for project test1...

17:10:23: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.

17:10:23: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 

g++ -c -pipe -g -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../test1 -I/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc/include -I/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc/include/QtCore -I. -I. -o main.o ../test1/main.cpp

g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc/lib -o test1 main.o   -L/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc/lib -lQt5Core -lpthread 
{ test -n "" && DESTDIR="" || DESTDIR=.; } && test $(gdb --version | sed -e 's,[^0-9][^0-9]*\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\).*,\1\2,;q') -gt 72 && gdb --nx --batch --quiet -ex 'set confirm off' -ex "save gdb-index $DESTDIR" -ex quit 'test1' && test -f test1.gdb-index && objcopy --add-section '.gdb_index=test1.gdb-index' --set-section-flags '.gdb_index=readonly' 'test1' 'test1' && rm -f test1.gdb-index || true

17:10:24: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.

17:10:24: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

EDIT:

For anyone who faces the same problem, Just as Nejat said I installed gdb 7.6 which fixed it.

Comment: did you compile the debug version?

Comment: Are you using QtCreator 3? What is your g++ version?

Comment: Yes I comiple the debug version and i'm using g++ 4.8

Comment: Are you sure that you are really in debug mode (check the compiler output)? Sometimes i have major trouble with QtCreator because even in debug mode makefile.release was triggered.

Comment: It doesn't say any thing about which make file it's calling. I added the compile output to my question.

Comment: But I don't think that's the problem since it shows global variable correctly.

Comment: what is the version of your gdb?

Comment: GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that gcc 4.8 is using a newer format for storing debugging information and you are using gdb version less than 7.5. You can check your gdb version by:

```
gdb --version
```

You should upgrade your gdb to the newest version.

The same symptom can result from having a gdb that is too new, instead of too old.